# New method does not see "this" (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods, this

Making a calculator that accepts new methods. But when I add a new method it does not see object's "this". Why Console.log returns "undefined"?

```js
function Calculator() {
  this.numbers = function() {
      this.numberOne = 2;
      this.numberTwo = 5;
    },
    this.addMethod = function(op, func) {
      this[op] = func(this.numberOne, this.numberTwo);

    // WHY LOG RETURNS "undefined"?
      console.log(this.numberOne);
    }
}

let calc = new Calculator();

calc.addMethod("/", (a, b) => (a / b));
document.write(calc["/"]);
```

Comment: You have a typo in line 5: the comma should be a semicolon.

Comment: `this.one` is never set, so yeah, it's `undefined`.

Comment: +goliadkin I think it works either way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not define `this.numberOne` and `this.numberTwo` before you tried to call the function on it. Moreover, you are printing `this.one` which is never defined in your code.

If you tried the following snippet:

```js
function Calculator() {
  this.numbers = function() {
    this.numberOne = 2;
    this.numberTwo = 5;
  },
    this.addMethod = function(op, func) {
    this[op] = func(this.numberOne, this.numberTwo);

    // WHY LOG RETURNS "undefined"?
    console.log(this.numberOne);
  }
}

let calc = new Calculator();
calc.numbers();
calc.addMethod("/", (a, b) => (a / b)); // 2/5
document.write(calc["/"]);
```

Then the code will work as expected because `calc.numberOne` and `calc.numberTwo` are defined

Comment: this.one was a typo. With calc.numbers(); all works! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers were not getting initialized.

Also you used `this.one` what's that? Did you mean `numberOne`.

Check out the working code below :

```js
function Calculator() {
  this.numberOne = 2;
  this.numberTwo = 5;
  this.addMethod = function(op, func) {
    this[op] = func(this.numberOne, this.numberTwo);
    // WHY LOG RETURNS "undefined"?
    console.log(this.numberOne, this.numberTwo );
  }
}

let calc = new Calculator();
calc.addMethod("/", (a, b) => (a / b));
document.write(calc["/"]);
```